# How can I import a partitioned table from Bigquery, that requires a partition filter, in Power BI?

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

Is there a way to import (not Direct Query) from Bigquery a partitioned table that requires a partition filter?

Here is the error I get (slightly edited)

```
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (70) Invalid query:
Cannot query over table 'project_name.dataset.table' without a filter over column(s)
'date' that can be used for partition elimination

Detalhes:
    DataSourceKind=GoogleBigQuery
    DataSourcePath=GoogleBigQuery
    OdbcErrors=[Table]
```

Here is the sequence of steps in Power BI (also slightly edited)

```
= GoogleBigQuery.Database([BillingProject="project_name"])
= Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] = "project_name"))
= #"project_name"{[Name="dataset_name",Kind="Schema"]}[Data]
= datasetName_Schema{[Name="table_name",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can see you accepted my answer, but please let us know if the solution works or not. Thus, my answer could be more helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: It is confirmed that the solution works for PowerBI**

Never imported anything to PowerBI, just suggest something to my knowledge.

I hope the PowerBI doesn't distinguish between BigQuery VIEW and TABLE, please try first. If it is true, the workaround can be to hardcode partition filter in a VIEW, then import the VIEW:

```sql
CREATE VIEW project_name.dataset.view AS 
SELECT * FROM project_name.dataset.table
WHERE date BETWEEN date_1 AND date_2;
```

**An alternative by @HuaZhang**

If you don't want to specify the date range, then below VIEW is simpler

```sql
CREATE VIEW project_name.dataset.view AS 
SELECT * FROM project_name.dataset.table
WHERE date IS NULL OR date IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: If you want to import the whole table, you can use "WHERE date IS NULL or date IS NOT NULL".